# KVM guest networking not working when on same vlan as the host

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, centos7, vlan, bridge

I have KVM running on a CentOS 7 host.  The host is connected to the switch with a single NIC to an untagged port, with the PVID set to VLAN 100.
I have set up VLAN networking on the host.

I believe the networks are set up in the same way as described [here](http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2012/05/05/kvm-brctl-in-linux-bringing-vlans-to-the-guests/) in the section 'Adding VLANs to the mix – the usual guest access mode'.  That is, I have a subinterface + bridge for every VLAN on the network, including the same VLAN as the host. (So 100, 200, 300, etc.) Everything works perfectly when creating a guest on a different VLAN to that of the host: the guest gets an IP from the router by DHCP, etc.

However, when I try to create a guest whose NIC is on the same VLAN as the host (using br100 whose interface is eth0.100, by analogy), it fails to get an IP address from the router. I don't understand why that is.

I experimented with the advice [here](https://blog.rackspace.com/vms-vlans-and-bridges-oh-my-part-2) which adds an ebtables rule to the routing table. It didn't work, but I don't know whether it should have done.

Can anybody break this down and explain why a guest on the same VLAN as the host can't get an IP address, and/or suggest whether an ebtables rule is the right way to work around this?

Comment: If your host machine is connected to the switch via an untagged port, how can the VMs on the machine connect to different VLANs? Could you add the output of `brctl show` and `ifconfig` on your host to the question?